# How to add russian language support to Django CMS?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I've installed Django CMS following guide http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html, but see only english language in interface.

I've looked at docs http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#i18n-l10n-reference, added `ru` to `LANGUAGES` and `CMS_LANGUAGES` variables in `settings.py`, russian language appeared in interface selector, but when I select it, it goes back to english and shows `"[15/Feb/2019 15:06:19] "GET /ru/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0"` in log.

Here is language related parts of my `settings.py`:

```
...
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
...
LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('en', gettext('en')),
    ('ru', gettext('ru'))
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
        },
        { 
            'code': 'ru',
            'name': gettext('ru'),
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
            'public': True,
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    },
}
...
```

Could anybody help me to translate my Django CMS installation?

Comment: Have you published the Russian version of the page that you're being shown in English?

Comment: @markwalker_, seems that it was reason. Published, now russian language seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

Generally need change to:
[changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0HOW.jpg)

And save. ))

Comment: include the code in your answer, not a link, and try and give more of an explanation as to what went wrong and why your solution works.